# Nginx regular expression location

Tags: python, regex, nginx

This regular expression doesn't work.

Below is the one.

```
    location ~* /a2aEx\?.*$ {

    }
```

I requested to `/a2aEx?AID=ASA_1&BID=1` but NGINX respond with `404 status`

However if I fix it to below, it works fine, returning `200 status`

```
    location ~* /a2aEx.*$ {   # remove `\?`

    }
```

I verify my regular expression on Python with below code.

```
 text = "/a2aEx?AID=ASA_1&BID=1"

 reObj = re.match("/a2aEx\?.*$", text)
 print reObj.string  # it returns `/a2aEx?AID=ASA_1&BID=1`
```

Seeing the symptom, the escape char(`\`) doesn't work as I expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression is fine. The issues lies with how Nginx is examining the incoming request.

Nginx treats anything after `?` as a query string in the request. `location` blocks match against the `$uri` variable (`/a2aEx`) in your example. Location blocks *do not* examine the `$args` variable, which is what you are attempting to match against.

Your second example matches the `$uri` variable correctly.

To operate on the arguments, you can use Nginx's `if` operator, but it is [generally discouraged.](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/)

Answer (score 0):

An escape problem?

Try one of the following:

- double the backslash

  ```
  location ~* /a2aEx\\?.*$ {
  ```
- put the regex in quotes

  ```
  location ~* "/a2aEx\?.*$" {
  ```
- replace by a character class

  ```
  location ~* "/a2aEx[?].*$" {
  ```

Comment: It is still the same as before, returning 404 status.